# Send Variable Data from Action Script 3 to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3

Since my AS3 and Php/Java knowledge is not good I got stuck on this problem.

I have a AS3 function that sends bitmap data to PHP file to save some image, and in this function I also added some other arguments and that new argument should give me a string value that i need.

```
private function saveImageForFacebook(evt:MouseEvent)


 // Sends the Bitmap data to php    


{
        var bitmapData:BitmapData=new BitmapData(wheelCanvas.width, wheelCanvas.height);
        bitmapData.draw(wheelCanvas); 
        var jpgEncoder:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder(80);
        var byteArray:ByteArray = jpgEncoder.encode(bitmapData);
        var header:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader ("Content-type", "application/octet-stream");
        var jpgURLRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest ("http://www.someurl.com/flash-test/saveimg.php");
        jpgURLRequest.requestHeaders.push(header);
        jpgURLRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
        jpgURLRequest.data = byteArray;
        navigateToURL(jpgURLRequest, "_blank");


 // Creates the string value that I need to use in saveimg.php


        var suffixUrl:String = "";
        for(var i:int=0; i < customizedColorArr.length; i++)
        {
             if(customizedColorArr[i] != "")
             {
                 suffixUrl += "&" + customizedPartValueArr[i] + "=" + customizedColorArr[i];
             }
        }
        suffixUrl = wheelName + "&variant_name=" + variantName + suffixUrl;
        trace(suffixUrl);

    }
```

Somehow I need to trace "suffixUrl" value in my saveimg.php file, but i don't know how.

This is how my php file looks and where suffixUrl need to go.

```
    <?php
    if ( isset ( $GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"] )) {
    $uniqueStamp = date(U);
    //$filename = "temp_image.jpg";
    $filename = $uniqueStamp . ".jpg";
    $fp = fopen( $filename,"wb");
    $result = fwrite( $fp, $GLOBALS[ 'HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA' ] );
    fclose( $fp );

    }
    ?>
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.someurl.com/flash-test/src_server/<?php echo $filename ; ?>" /> 
 <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
     function redirect () {
     window.location.href = "http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://www.someurl/flash-test/Main3D.html?"+suffixUrl, '_self';
}
 </SCRIPT>
   <BODY onload="redirect()">
```

You will see "suffixUrl" in my javascript function. That's where I'm trying to treace that value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to send a variable to **Javascript**; you want to send a variable to **PHP**.

Move the suffix generation code block above the Bitmap sending part, and then change this line.

```
var jpgURLRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest ("http://www.someurl.com/flash-test/saveimg.php?suffixUrl=" + suffixUrl);
```

Then, in the **PHP**

```
window.location.href = "http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://www.someurl/flash-test/Main3D.html?" + <?php echo $_GET['suffixUrl'] ?>, '_self';
```

This will work, but you will also have to **sanitize** the input for **security**.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your "php file" is the one that's embedding your Flash, you can use ExternalInterface to call your `redirect` function from Flash.

Flash :

```
ExternalInterface.call("redirect", suffixUrl);
```

Note : You need to import `flash.external.ExternalInterface;`

JavaScript :

```
function redirect (suffixUrl) {
     window.location.href = "http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://www.someurl/flash-test/Main3D.html?" + suffixUrl;
}
```

Comment: the problem is I'm trying to pass that value to saveimg.php which I'm already using it to save images in the same AS function.